# MySQL sub queries - find rooms a user is in, and find other people in a room

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table that has users and rooms. A user can be in multiple rooms, and what I'd like to do is find what rooms a user is in, AND what other people are in the same room in one query operation.

```
SELECT user, room FROM rooms WHERE user='foobar'
```

I could simply have another query after that is `SELECT user FROM rooms WHERE room='theroom'`, but is there any way to cut down on the MySQL queries and provide a performance benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `rooms` table on itself:

```
SELECT r1.user, r1.room, r2.user 
FROM 
   rooms r1 JOIN rooms r2 ON r2.room = r1.room 
WHERE r1.user='foobar'AND r2.user != 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT r.user, r.room
  FROM rooms r JOIN rooms x ON r.room=x.room
  WHERE x.user='foobar';
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you can use 'IN' clause in you query......

SELECT user from rooms where room in (SELECT room from rooms where user = 'foobar');